# PostgreSQL view with filtered columns

Tags: postgresql

i have a table like this:

```
date_added        owner        action
01-02-2016        1            note
04-02-2016        1            call
04-02-2016        1            call
05-02-2016        1            note
05-02-2016        1            meeting
06-02-2016        1            meeting
06-02-2016        1            note
06-02-2016        1            cal
06-02-2016        1            note
10-02-2016        1            call
10-02-2016        1            note
10-02-2016        1            meeting
```

I need a view like this:

```
date_added        owner        note        call        meeting
01-02-2016        1            1           0           0
04-02-2016        1            0           2           0
05-02-2016        1            0           0           1
06-02-2016        1            2           1           1
10-02-2016        1            1           1           1
```

How do i create a column with something like

```
WHERE action LIKE 'note'
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `CASE` expression.

**Query**

```
select date_added, owner,
sum(case action when 'note' then 1 else 0 end) note,
sum(case action when 'call' then 1 else 0 end) call,
sum(case action when 'meeting' then 1 else 0 end) meeting
from your_table_name
group by date_added, owner;
```

**[Find demo here](http://rextester.com/NAUZP32448)**

Comment: okay great. this however returns 1 for each row. Can I put a SUM inside the case?

Comment: No.. You cannot.

Comment: Is it not possible to get the number of meetings per day?

Comment: In the result set, meeting column gives the number of meetings per day only right

Comment: I see. then it was my fault. I use a `SELECT DISTINCT ON (date_added, owner)` to get thetable.therefore it does not work for me.  I'll try to figure it out or else ask again. Your answer is the correct one however.